# How to find row indexes in A where columns 1 and 3 are equal to B (without a for loop) in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Given 2 numpy arrays A and B as following :

```
A =
[[  1, 200,  15],
 [  0, 600,  25],
 [  2, 200,  20],
 [  3, 100,  10],
 [  1, 300,   5],
 [  4, 400,   3],
 [  0, 100,  12],
 [  5, 300,   2],
 [  2, 300,  25],
 [  6, 100,   1],
 [  1, 400,  74],
 [  7, 300,  10],
 [  2, 400,  15],
 [  8, 200,  13],
 [  3, 400,  29],
 [  3, 600,  37],
 [  0, 200,  20],
 [  9, 300,  42],
 [  5, 400,  30],
 [  6, 200,  51],
 [  7, 400,  21],
 [  9, 500,   5],
 [ 10, 300,   9] ]


B =
[[ 0, 25.],
 [ 1, 74.],
 [ 2, 25.],
 [ 3, 37.],
 [ 4,  3.],
 [ 5, 30.],
 [ 6, 51.],
 [ 7, 21.],
 [ 8, 13.],
 [ 9, 42.],
 [10,  9.]]
```

What is the efficient way (Without a FOR loop) to compute indexes of rows in the array A
where column 0 and 2 of A form the array B?

The expected answer is i:

```
i = [ 1,  5,  8, 10, 13, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22]
```

So that:

```
A[i,:] == B
```

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Start by grabbing the first and third columns of `A` with

   ```
   >>> A[:,(0,2)]
   ```
2. Then compare all possible rows pairs `(A[i], B[j])` using a [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) trick and [`np.equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html):

   ```
   >>> np.equal(A[:,(0,2)][:,None], B[None])
   ```
3. Make sure all elements in the row are matching using [`np.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

   ```
   >>> np.equal(A[:,(0,2)][:,None], B[None]).all(2)
   ```
4. Lastly, look at the argmax on the first axis, this assumes there is at least one match in `A` for each row of `B`:

   ```
   >>> np.equal(A[:,(0,2)][:,None], B[None]).all(2).argmax(0)
   ```

   The above line won't work for instance if you remove `B` last row. On one of the rows all *equal* conditions are false (no match at all in `B`) but argmax will still pick the first `False` value, *i.e.* returning index `0`... which is not a very general solution.

   A more accurate method is to use [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) instead to catch only the non-zeros which is exactly what we want here:

   ```
   >>> np.equal(A[:,(0,2)][:,None], B[None]).all(2).nonzero()[0]
   ```

Comment: Can  you explain the "broadcasting trick" a bit.   I have seen this multiple times, but I am having a hard time visualizing exactly that is going on here.  Thank you.

Comment: This trick involves adding in an extra dimension on opposite sides. Take this example: `A = np.arange(1,4)` and `B = np.arange(1,4)`. Then `A[None]` will have a shape of `(1, 3)`, while `B[:, None]` will have a shape of `(3, 1)`. When used in conjunction with an operator (above it was `np.equal`), then the operation will not be performed element wise (that would be the case if you had given `A`, and `B`) but instead will look at all pair combinations. An intuitive example is the `*` operator: `A*B` is the element-wise product while `A[None]*B[:,None]` is the outer product between `A` and `B`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I think I have it now.   I appreciate the time you volunteer to SO.   Be safe and stay healthy.